# C++-amp libraries and software requirements

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gpgpu, c++-amp

My Visual Studio version does not have GPU debugger option. is it because of the version itself or should I download some updates? The version is "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2","Windows 7 home premium SP1" what about libraries, where can I get them?

Answer (score 2):

> Debugging is supported on Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008
>   R2, and Windows Server 2012. For debugging on the software emulator,
>   Windows 8, or Windows Server 2012 is required. For debugging on the
>   hardware, you must install the drivers for your graphics card. Not all
>   hardware vendors implement all debugger features. See the vendor
>   documentation for limitations.
>
> Independent hardware vendors who want to support GPU debugging in
>   Visual Studio must create a DLL that implements the VSD3DDebug
>   interface and targets their own drivers.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873126.aspx

Comment: Debugging will be on hardware, I checked the device using a sample code. but on VS I cannot find this option **GPU Only** among the debugger options.

Answer (score 2):

For windows 7 there are some additional downloads. It is not supported out of the box.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2013/01/25/c-amp-gpu-debugging-now-available-on-windows-7.aspx

This will give you debugging on the WARP software emulator on windows 7. You GPU, and more importantly the driver you have for it may or may not support debugging.

I believe GPU debugging is supported on Express, it was for the VS11 Preview.

This should get you started.

Comment: one more question, how can I know if my driver support debugging or not as I downloaded the update and the only debugging options I still have are `Release` and `Debug` . My driver is `AMD Radeon(TM) HD 6470M`

Comment: BTW: I believe debugging on win7 is now supported out of the box in VS 2013